# Chessboard domination problem for a new piece (called Wazir)

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve a [chessboard domination problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_chess_problem#Domination_problems), but for a new piece, which is called [Wazir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wazir_%28chess%29) (thanks to @bof for pointing that out) which only threatens the neighbouring squares meaning the ones that share an edge with each other. Also the size of the chessboard is not $8\times 8$ but is arbitrary; $M\times N$. What I have found so far is the calculation for small cases by try and error for $4\times 2,4\times 3,4\times 4, 4\times 5, 4\times 6, 4\times 7$ and for $5\times 2,5\times 3,5\times 4, 5\times 5, 5\times 6$.

Updated chart:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
4   2   3   4   4   6   7   7
5   2   3   4   6   7   8   9(thanks to @bof)
```

Can I get any hint for this?

This problem is supposed to be a math project for a college student, and the idea I have in my mind is complex for college level math:

One can see that we define a grid graph corresponding to the chessboard of size $(M-1)\times (N-1)$ by connecting the associated vertices to the squares of checkerboard if they are neighbour on checkerboard.

UPDATE:

The set that we are after is the dominating set for this grid graph. It seems the problems is open as there exist only bounds for it:
http://www.emis.de/journals/EJC/Volume_18/PDF/v18i1p141.pdf

I would be very happy if somebody could acknowledge what I am saying here.

Comment: Are you looking for a fomula that holds for any board size?

Comment: Your "new piece" is called a [wazir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wazir_(chess)).

Comment: @ZurLuria, Yes sir, thats right.

Comment: It's not a random bipartite graph, though, it's very specific.  Did you try running Hopcroft-Karp by hand on it and seeing if there's an easy-to-detect pattern?  (Not a rhetorical question; I'm asking.)

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, I just realised my idea was wrong as vertex cover is not equivalent to this threatening problem!

Comment: The $5\times7$ chessboard (with corners a1 and g5) is dominated by $9$ wazirs placed at a4, b1, b2, c5, d3, e1, f4, f5, g2.

Comment: The numbers you listed seem to be at odds with the quoted article (yours are slightly higher in some cases; you might want to re-check them).

Comment: @PeterKošinár, these are by try and error. I didn't recheck them. I will do it right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The area covered by this piece (the "wazir") is the shape of a plus sign.  It's straightforward to tile the plane with five-square plus signs, so your "piece fraction" approaches $0.2$ as the board gets big.  Each open square is attacked by exactly one of these pieces well away from one of the edges.  These wazirs would be arranged in a tilted square lattice that could be traversed by a chess knight.

The periodicity of this tiling pattern is $5 \times 5$.  In other words, if you displace the entire pattern by $5a \hat{x} + 5b \hat{y}$, it will map onto itself.

The edges of the board are where the deviations happen.  Extra wazirs have to be placed to cover the squares where the infinite plane symmetry is broken.  Specifically, every fifth square on the edge will need to be "plugged up" by a wazir because it's left unattacked.

The problem now is to minimize the sum of the number of edge squares that need to be plugged up, plus the number of non-edge squares that need to be occupied by a wazir.

Since the pattern repeats by displacing it a multiple of $5$ squares in either direction, we only need to consider the grid size modulo $5$ to determine the deviations at the edge.

The answer will be of the form

$$K(M,N) = \lfloor\frac{MN + 2(M+N)}{5}\rfloor + E(M (\text{mod } 5), N (\text{mod } 5)),$$

where $E(M (\text{mod } 5), N (\text{mod } 5)) = E(N (\text{mod } 5), M (\text{mod } 5))$ is an adjustment function.

So for a grid size of $M \times N$ let's look at the cases.  By symmetry, we can consider only those for which $M \leq N$ (mod $5$).

By explicit calculation for $M = 10 ... 14, N = 10 ... 14,$ I found:

$$E(0,0) = E(1,0) = E(2,0) = E(3,0) = E(4,0) = 0;$$

$$E(1,1) = E(1,2) = E(1,3) = E(1,4) = -1;$$

$$E(2,2) = -2; E(2,3) = E(2,4)= -1;$$

$$E(3,3) = E(3,4) = -1;$$

$$E(4,4) = -2.$$

This likely breaks down for small $M, N$.  I was looking more to shed light on the general case above.

For small boards, there are other behaviors.  $M=1$ is interesting in that the wazirs can have two blanks between them in the optimal configurations for $N > 3$.  (They must for $N > 5$.)  This is related to the fact that the board size limits their attack field to two squares.  Hence the piece fraction $\geq 1/3.$  So $K(M, 1) = \lceil M/3 \rceil.$

For $M=2$, the board size limits the attack field to three squares, and the piece fraction hence $\geq 1/4$.  From my observations, for $M \geq 2$, $K(M,2) = \lceil (M+1)/2 \rceil.$

Comment: Hmm... your formula seems to be at odds with the results in the article provided by original poster. In particular, for $M=N=11$, you predict $32$ while the true number is apparently $29$. Similar discrepancies appear for other dimensions too; perhaps you forgot to include an extra term of $-4$ somewhere?

Comment: Thank you very much, vote up, but I am not following... as I can see the problem is open and the article I have posted tries to cover special cases. Now should I assume this answers the open problem?

Comment: Plus, I think what you are achieving is a upper bound as there is no guarantee that tiling the $5\times 5$ sub-checkerboards, will give the minimum tiling number for the whole checkerboard.

Comment: I wasn't just tiling the $5 \times 5$ sub-checkerboards.  I just noted the symmetry.  As I was playing with it, I tiled a large board (in a spreadsheet) and moved around the $M \times N$ window to get the minimum number of wazirs that would attack all squares in that window.  But this does probably break down for small $M, N$.  Really interesting problem; burned several hours late at night playing with it. :)

Comment: @Naji Ahhh, OK, I see what you mean (I think).  I tiled the board as if I were tiling the infinite plane, and cookie-cuttered a part of that.  But for large $M,N$ far away from the edge, I think the positions need to be as described.  I don't see any other way that doesn't create a lot of holes.

Comment: @PeterKošinár There must be subtlety I'm overlooking.  Thanks!

Comment: @John, so sorry for my late reply. So I am not following are you suggesting that your solution only works for infinitely large planes?? I don't know wether you checked or not but I pointed out that problem in the form that I stated is an open problem and there is ongoing research on it.

Btw... its my pleasure! thank you for spending time and trying to answer it.